# find all hash # links in a div and remove hash for the last twenty ones

Tags: jquery, hash

I got a div with a links to gallery pictures which are generated by a script. There are -let say x numbers of links + 20 which are alwas generated by the script. 
So every of the link has a # and number. Like www.example.com/#1. 
So in a gallery I can have e.g 5 pictures which will have #1 #2 #3,etc and those 20 that are always generated with the number starting in this case from #6 #7 till 26#.

So my question is how to find with jQuery those last twenty url's and remove # from them.

Arek

Answer (score 3):

```
var start = $("div a").length - 21;
start = start < 0 ? 0 : start;

$("div a:gt(" + start + ")[href^='#']").each(function() {
    var $a = $(this);
    $a.attr("href", $a.attr("href").replace("#", ""));
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/958ea/2/

---

**Explained**

`var start = $("div a").length - 21;` will set `start` to the total number of `a` tags minus 21. 20 + 1 since length is the total count but we need the 0-based index.

So if there were `500` anchor tags `start` would be equal to `479`;

`start = start < 0 ? 0 : start;` will reset `start` to `0` if somehow there weren't 20 `a` tags present. *For this example this probably isn't necessary, but a nice check so things don't break.*

Then we loop through the `a` tags using this selector: `"div a:gt(" + start + ")[href^='#']"` which is going to select all `a` tags with an index greater than the value of `start` (which in my example is index = 10 which is `<a href="#11">`). Next it further filters on `a` tags that start-with `#`. *This might also be unnecessary but is another good thing to check.*

Finally the `#` character in `href` is replaced with the empty string `""`

Comment: That looks to find the all links after the 20th link, not the last 20 like the description says. In the description he says that links #6-#26 were the ones that needed to be changed.

Comment: @user - it doesn't do what you think. check out the example and you will see that it has selected the last 20 anchor tags

Comment: @user the example selects the last 20. The OP miscalculated. #6 to #26 would be 21 items, not 20. Should be #7-#26 or #6-#25

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div > a").each(function() {
    var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var newURL = linkURL.replace("#", "");
    //Do something with newURL here.
    //eg. to assign it the new url:
    //$(this).attr("href", newURL);
});
```

This will target every div with anchor tags in it, so if you have more than one, give the div an id and target it like this instead

```
$("#theIdYouChose > a").each(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [jQuery nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). Just from reading it should look something like

```
$('body > a:nth-child(n+20)').each(function() {
    var _href = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    $(this).attr("href", _href);
});
```

Edit: Nevermind... this will select all links after the 20th link. Not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace "#" with "" in an anchor it doesnt appear as a link in most of the browser. Try this

```
var lastAnchor = $("div a[href='#']:last"), count = 0;
while(count++ <= 20){
   lastAnchor  = lastAnchor.attr("href", "javascript:void(0)").prev("a[href='#']");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer above you can simplify things a bit:

```
$.each(("div a[href^='#']").slice(-20), function() {
    var $a = $(this);
    $a.attr("href", $a.attr("href").replace("#", ""));
});
```

slice(-20) will grab the last 20 elements of the array.